# Browser work in background

Tags: javascript, webkit, chromium

I want to build a web browser for windows which would work in the background (without opening a window). Regarding the scheme below, I want to get rid of the user interface layer, but still render objects and build the DOM tree and everything else. I just want to bypass the painting stuff.

USER INTERFACE
-----------|---------------
BROWSER ENGINE
-----------|---------------
RENDERING ENGINE
---|---------------------------|---------------------|--------
networking   |  JavaScript interpreter | UI  Backend
I know that open source browsers like chromium or mozilla use third party browser engines and rendering engines (like webkit or gecko which handle html, css, etc.) and JavaScript engines (like V8) and chromium and mozilla provide the UI.

1) Is it possible to create a browser without user interface (to run in the background)?

2) If yes, where should I start? Should I use Chromium project and try to eliminate the UI? Should I use the WebKit project?

Comment: Take a look at  : http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: 10x this is what I needed